# Constructing and getting an Array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function that counts the week difference between two dates.Users must pick a Saturday or Sunday (start and end of week) The next step, is to have the document create

elements that enumerate each week within the selected range.

Here is my JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jafaoej5/1/

```
var $arr = [];
while(lowEnd <= totalweeks.innerHTML){
    arr.push(lowEnd++);}

console.log( $( "arr" ).get()) ;
    });
```

This is some code that I am trying to use to console log the total number in weeks. From there I will do a math operation to do the conversion operations with UTC time. The problem is that I can't get my array. How can I get my array?

Comment: you named your array `$arr`, but are trying to use `arr`

Answer (score 2):

You're creating `$arr` but pushing into `arr` ??

This is how I think it should be:

```
var $arr = []; // Or just use 'arr' instead of '$arr'

while (lowEnd <= totalweeks.innerHTML) {
  // The above 'while' also needs modification because you're using lowEnd
  // as an integer whereas innerHtml will return a string
  // MAYBE this is what you want:
  // var totalWeeks = parseInt(totalweeks.innerHTML) || 0;
  // while (lowEnd <= totalWeeks) {}

  $arr.push(lowEnd++);

  console.log($arr);
});
```

As for the `get()` function, I don't know what you were trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you want difference in weeks you can do just that:

```
var firstDate = new Date("7/11/2010"); // get those through datepicker
var secondDate = new Date("12/12/2010");

// calculate difference in timestamp (miliseconds)
var timestampDiff = Math.abs(secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime());
// convert the difference into weeks, use ceil to round up (started weeks), use floor to roun down (full weeks)
var weeksDiff = Math.ceil(timestampDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7)); 

console.log(weeksDiff)​;
```

As for the array: `$arr` and `arr` are not the same, I would suggest using `$` in naming variables that are  objects, so in this case `arr` is better.

It is not a good idea to limit oyor loop with `innerHtml` because you will get an error if it will be something other than number.

```
// declare an array
var arr = [];
while(lowEnd <= parseInt(totalweeks.innerHTML)){
    arr.push(lowEnd++);}
});
// print it once it's complete
console.log(arr);
```